# How to split this string into it's individual characters?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using this html section of code in a BeautifulSoup object...

```
<span class="Example1" data-test-selector="RC1">
 507
        <b>
         3
        </b>
        <b>
         3
        </b>
        <b>
         2
        </b>
</span>
```

I'm using this code to split it...

```
hList = []
for each in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'Example1'}):
    hList.append(each.text.split())

print(hList)
```

I get the result...

```
['507', '3', '3', '2']
```

When I actually want...

```
['5', '0', '7', '3', '3', '2']
```

I have tried to separate the '507' using all manner of list comprehensions, nested methods, etc. I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: I Think you get as result `[['507', '3', '3', '2']]` (so two brackets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Note**: you probably obtain as result `[['507', '3', '3', '2']]` instead of `['507', '3', '3', '2']` since the findall only finds one element, and then you split it and append that.

With `each.text.split()` you obtain a list of strings. A string is an iterable of strings (1-character strings that are the characters of the string). By using `.extend(..)` instead and *flatten* the outcome of `each.text.split()`, we can add every character separately to the list:

```
hList = []
for each in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'Example1'}):
    hList.extend([c for cs in each.text.split() for c in cs])

print(hList)
```

Or we convert it into complete list comprehension:

```
hList = [c for each in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'Example1'})
           for cs in each.text.split()
           for c in cs]

print(hList)
```

Comment: I actually simplified the example and gave only one html section, of which there are many. So in my case I have use *append* instead of extend, to create a list of lists. Either way, you have solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Join the strings in the list into a single string, then call `list()` on that string:

```
>>> hList = ['507', '3', '3', '2']
>>> list(''.join(hList))
['5', '0', '7', '3', '3', '2']
```

Your code actually constructs a list of lists, so you need to flatten the list before applying `str.join()`. That can be done with a list comprehension to create `hList`:

```
>>> hList = [s for each in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'Example1'})
                for s in each.text.split()]
>>> list(''.join(hList))
['5', '0', '7', '3', '3', '2']
```

Comment: You have taught me a new way to think about this thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be something like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content='''
<span class="Example1" data-test-selector="RC1">
    507
    <b>
     3
    </b>
    <b>
     3
    </b>
    <b>
     2
    </b>
</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
for items in soup.select('.Example1'):
    data = ' '.join([item for item in items.text])
    print(data.split())
```

Output:

```
['5', '0', '7', '3', '3', '2']
```